# c# - Paramaters with ObjectDataSource Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, 2-tier

I have a 2-tier architecture, which means I'm working with Business Objects and DAL classes. My question is: how do you pass a value to the parameters of one of the functions in a DAL class.

I'm working with a gridview (where I display essential information) and a formview (where all of the information of one single record is shown when you click the select button in the gridview).

this is the function in my DAL class:

```
    [DataObjectMethodAttribute(DataObjectMethodType.Select, true)]
    public static Inschrijving GetInschrijvingById(int id)
    {
        Inschrijving inschrijving = new Inschrijving();

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
        string sql =
          "SELECT * FROM tblInschrijvingen WHERE ID = @id";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            inschrijving.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ID"]);
            inschrijving.Naam = dr["NAAM"].ToString();
            inschrijving.Geslacht = dr["GESLACHT"].ToString();
            inschrijving.Straat = dr["STRAAT"].ToString();
            inschrijving.Postcode = Convert.ToInt32(dr["PC"]);
            inschrijving.Gemeente = dr["PLAATS"].ToString();
            inschrijving.Geboortedatum = (DateTime) dr["GBDATUM"];
            inschrijving.Tshirt = dr["TSHIRT"].ToString();
            inschrijving.Afstand = DAL.AfstandDAL.getAfstandByID(Convert.ToInt32(dr["ID_AFSTAND"]));
            inschrijving.Email = dr["EMAIL"].ToString();
            inschrijving.InschrijvingsDatum = (DateTime)dr["INDATUM"];
            inschrijving.Betaald = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["BETAALD"]);
        }

        return inschrijving;
    }
```

And I have this Object Datasource:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="dtsrcDetails" runat="server" SelectMethod="getInschrijvingById" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" TypeName="DAL.InschrijvingDAL" DataObjectTypeName="BO.Inschrijving"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

I know I'm supposed to add some SelectParameter, I just don't know how.
Anyone that is willing to help me? :)

Thanks in advance. 
H.S.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ObjectDataSource.SelectParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.selectparameters%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property.

This msdn article describes how to use parameters - [Using Parameters with the ObjectDataSource Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57hkzhy5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following method to add parameters to be passed to the select method

```
  <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="dtsrcDetails" runat="server" SelectMethod="getInschrijvingById" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" TypeName="DAL.InschrijvingDAL" DataObjectTypeName="BO.Inschrijving"><SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="id" />  
  </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```